# Haus: parliament or ministry?

Tags: translation

Consider [this passage](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/inland/kramp-karrenbauer-ueber-tornardo-nachfolger-bis-ostern-entscheiden-16699549.html):

Context: The German defence ministry was planning to replace its ageing fleet of Tornado fighters with new aircraft.

> Verteidigungsministerin Kramp-Karrenbauer (CDU) will die Entscheidung
>   ungeachtet der Corona-Krise noch vor Ostern **für ihr Haus** bekanntgeben.
>   Der F.A.Z. sagte die Ministerin, es sollten keine Abstriche bei der
>   Sicherheit gemacht werden, das stehe auch im Einklang mit der
>   Haushaltsplanung.

I am confused about the bolded part. My first thought was the minister was going to announce the decision to the parliament, which is referred to as *Haus*. But ***ihr*** Haus doesn't really make sense because it's not her parliament. And why *für* and not *vor* or *zu*, when you are announcing something before the parliament?

Then I thought maybe it's trying to say the minister will announce the decision of her ministry and it's the ministry that's being referred to by *Haus*, but the question of **für** remains. Surely a decision of the ministry would have a *von* and not a *für*?

So, what is *Haus* referring to, and what would be the translation of *für ihr Haus bekanntgeben*?

Comment: Dass im Zusammenhang mit Corona keine Abstriche gemacht werden sollen, ist für den non-native Leser möglicherweise auch verwirrend. Hier im Sinne von "no reductions", nicht im Sinne von "no swabs".

Comment: It might be worth noting that *House* suggests itself much more as a short term for Westminster-inspired parliament systems where the individual chambers are called ***House** of Lords/Commons/Representatives*. In the UK, *House* itself is ambiguous but in the US or Australia the *House* would always be that of Representatives making the short term far more common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The German parliaments are never referred to as *das Haus*. That's a false friend. The proper German term is

> der Bundestag, der Landtag, der Kreistag
>
> der Stadtrat, der Gemeinderat, der Ortsrat

(*der Landrat* in contrast is the head of the executive in a *Kreis — county*, and *der Bundesrat* is the parliament of the state executives on the federal republic's level.)

---

*but the question of für remains.*

She has decided it **on behalf** of her staff. *Das Haus* is commonly used in a sense of company, greater family.

> Unser Haus freut sich, ihnen folgendes Angebot unterbreiten zu dürfen: …
>
> Das »House of Windsor« ist ja eigentlich das Haus Sachsen-Coburg und Gotha.

Comment: According to Duden, Haus can indeed refer to parliament: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Haus, 2b

Comment: But not to a German parliament. We call the UK parliaments *das Unterhaus* and *das Oberhaus* for example.

Comment: _Haus_ can refer to the Austrian Parlament, though. But usually in the form [_Hohes Haus_](https://www.parlament.gv.at/PERK/PARL/POL/ParluVfGH/index.shtml).

Comment: The term *Hohes Haus* can be used for a parliament, mostly in a formal context.

Comment: Die Aussage im ersten Teil stimmt nicht. Schon bevor das Buch *Das Hohe Haus* des guten Roger Willemsen herauskam, war mir als Synonym für den Bundestag der Begriff *Hohes Haus* geläufig. Ich kann mich erinnern, dass auch Norbert Lammert den Bundestag, dessen Präsident er 12 Jahre war, zuweilen so genannt hat. Link zum Buch: https://www.fischerverlage.de/buch/roger_willemsen_das_hohe_haus/9783596521395

Comment: Ja, poetisch halt. Ist aber immer noch *Hohes Haus* und nicht *das Haus* — The House, wie es im Englischen als Eigenname des Unterhauses täglich in den Nachrichten verwendet wird.

Comment: @Janka: Was ist mit dem Abgeordnetenhaus

Comment: Das sind wie gesagt alles Verbindungen, wogegen das im Text genannte *das Haus* niemals für ein deutsches Parlament steht, ganz im Gegensatz z.B. zum Englischen. Und deshalb kann man das im deutschen Satz auch nur verwechseln, wenn man einem *false friend* auf den Leim geht.

Comment: Nein, das hohe Haus kann natürlich auch ganz zu Haus gekürzt werden, wenn es sich aus dem Kontext ergibt, solches macht man im Deutschen laufend. Aus Eisenbahn o. Bundesbahn wird Bahn, wie umgekehrt aus der Bahn die Eisenbahn erst wurde o. a. d. Haus das Abgeordnetenhaus. Aber das Parlament ist natürlich nicht das Haus eines Ministers, deswegen kann es im konkreten Fall nicht gemeint sein.

Comment: Ich bitte um Beispiele, in denen ein deutsches Parlament konkret als "das Haus" bezeichnet wird. In der Art, wie es im Englischen geschieht. *Die Koalition bringt ihre Gesetzesvorlage vor das Haus.* — *Gute Idee, ab in den Müll damit.*

Comment: @Janka: Du verschiebst die Torpfosten. Ich habe nicht behauptet, dass es im Deutschen wie im Englischen benutzt wird, nur dass man auch im Dt. auch das Parlament gelegentlich als Haus bezeichnet. "Wir bringen die Gesetzesvorlage ins Abgeordnetenhaus ein, aber dann muss das Haus natürlich erst einmal darüber diskutieren." Ähnlich kannst Du mit dem Hohen Haus verfahren. Siehe Paul Frosts Beispiele, offensichtlich belegt, leider ohne den Kern der Frage zu beantworten, wieso "für ihr Haus", nicht "von ihrem Haus".

Comment: Ich habe in meiner Antwort von Anfang an ganz klar herausgestellt, dass man "das Haus" nicht für deutsche Parlamente verwendet, und dass es daher auch keine Verwechselungen geben kann. Es handelt sich ganz klar um einen falschen Freund, dem der OP da erlegen ist. Die ganze restliche Diskussion dreht sich darum, wie andere diese Antwort missverstehen.

Answer (score 6):

In this context Ms. Kramp-Karrenbauer is definitely refering to the *Bundesministerium der Verteidigung* (ministry of defence). She can only speak and *decide* (*die Entscheidung*) for her own area of competence (*für ihr Haus*), but not for the whole parliament.

Nevertheless, the phrase *Haus* is frequently also used for the parliament. This will not occur in official documents, but in speeches in parliament. Examples:

> Das ganze Haus hat meiner Feststellung, die Kosten der Einheit seien kalkulierbar und sie würden nicht höher sein als der Zuwachs des Bruttoinlandsprodukts bei angemessenem  Wachstum, zugestimmt.
>   [Source](http://dipbt.bundestag.de/doc/btp/14/106/14112106.12.pdf)
>
> Meine Damen und Herren, wir Politiker, alle in diesem Haus, haben das über Jahre hinweg gesagt.
>   [Source](https://www.bundestag.de/parlament/geschichte/debatte/bdr_074-246672)
>
> Wir haben, liebe Kolleginnen und Kollegen, in diesem Haus zweifellos immer wieder herausragende Debatten erlebt; aber bei selbstkritischer Betrachtung sollten wir einräumen, dass in der Regel hier im Hause immer noch zu häufig geredet und zu wenig debattiert wird.
>   [Source](https://www.bundestag.de/parlament/praesidium/reden/2017/006-525764)

Comment: Schön belegt! Es fehlt noch die Frage wieso "für ihr Haus", nicht "von". Evtl. noch ein Hinweis auf Firmen ("unser Haus bringt nächstes Jahr den XY auf den Markt").

Answer (score 3):

> Ihr Haus

refers to the ministry that she leads. As already pointed out by others, *Haus* on its own doesn't refer to the parliament.

*Für ihr Haus* -- in my understanding -- is part of the construction

> für ihr Haus bekanntgeben 
>   (not: <s>Entscheidung für ihr Haus</s>)

and hence means that she announces the decision *speaking for* her ministry (not: a decision *regarding* her house)